# Do C++ compilers optimize template methods based on template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

Are C++ compilers able to optimize a code like this in a way that concrete method implementations ( `if (little_endian)` => `if(true)`or `if(false)`) would only contain the relevant code or do I need to use `type_traits` and provide two separate implementations in order to ensure that my code will be optimized (i.e. no branch prediction)?

```
template <typename T, bool little_endian = true> bool readValue(T& value)
{
    if (m_num_bytes_parsed + sizeof(value) <= m_num_bytes_total)
    {
        if (little_endian)
        {
            m_file_stream.read((char *)(&value), sizeof(value));                    
        }
        else
        {
            char bytes[sizeof(T)];
            m_file_stream.read((char *)(&value), sizeof(value));
            std::reverse(bytes, bytes + sizeof(value));
            memcpy(&value, bytes, sizeof(T));
        }
        m_num_bytes_parsed += sizeof(value);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, they can and do and not just in templated code but in all conditional statements containing constant expressions that can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every compiler worth its salt will optimize `if(true)` and `if(false)` and otherwise collapse simple constant expressions.

There may be some obscure compilers that fail to do this.  To be explicit, current versions of gcc, clang, intel and msvc will all do this to my knowledge, and I haven't run into a compiler that does not do this.